# PyInstaller ImportError: No module named spiderloader

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, scrapy, pyinstaller

Trying to create `exe` file from my `Scrapy` project. I've created `main.py` file in the root of `Scrapy` project:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from engine_bot.engine_bot.spiders.main_spider import MainSpider


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess({'BOT_NAME':'engine_bot',
    'SPIDER_MODULES':['engine_bot.engine_bot.spiders'],
    'NEWSPIDER_MODULE':'engine_bot.engine_bot.spiders',
    'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY':False,
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY':0.20,
    'LOG_FILE':'scrapy.log',
    'LOG_LEVEL':'INFO',
    'ITEM_PIPELINES':{
    'engine_bot.engine_bot.pipelines.XmlExportPipeline': 300,
    }
    })
    process.crawl(MainSpider)
    process.start()
```

And created a `main.exe`: `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

When I run `main.exe` it raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot\main.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 243, in __init__
  File "site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 134, in __init__
  File "site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 320, in _get_spider_loader
  File "site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 44, in load_object
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
ImportError: No module named spiderloader
[10280] Failed to execute script main
```

Tried without --onefile with the same result. Do you know what to do?

Comment: can you post the log or output of the pyinstaller call. That way we can see what pyinstaller is doing while it builds your exe.

Comment: did you try from scrapy.spiderloader import SpiderLoader ?

Comment: Where? It's not in my script. It's scrapy (probably dynamic) import.

Answer (score 0):

I use `pyinstaller -F filename.py --hidden-import spiderloader`
and after pass this case will stuck in other module too,
so I add many hidden import.

For me this work.